# no me aparecen las X y O en un tic tac toe

Tags: c#

estoy tratando de hacer un tic tac toe, y no me quieren aparecer las X y las O cuando doy click en los botones, este es el código que tengo.`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int turno = 1;

        private void btniniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            habilitar();
            lbljugadas.Text = turno.ToString();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            deshabilitar();
        }
        void deshabilitar()
        {
            btn1.Enabled = false;
            btn2.Enabled = false;
            btn3.Enabled = false;
            btn4.Enabled = false;
            btn5.Enabled = false;
            btn6.Enabled = false;
            btn7.Enabled = false;
            btn8.Enabled = false;
            btn9.Enabled = false;

        }
        void habilitar()
        {
            btn1.Enabled = true;
            btn2.Enabled = true;
            btn3.Enabled = true;
            btn4.Enabled = true;
            btn5.Enabled = true;
            btn6.Enabled = true;
            btn7.Enabled = true;
            btn8.Enabled = true;
            btn9.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnsalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn1.Text = Jugadas();
            btn1.Enabled = false;
        }
        public string Jugadas()
        {
            string variacion = "";
            if (turno == 1)
            {
                variacion = "x";
                turno = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                variacion = "o";
                turno = 1;
            }
            lbljugadas.Text = turno.ToString();
            return variacion;
        }

        void validar()
        {
            if (btn1.Text == "x" && btn2.Text == "x" && btn3.Text == "x")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 1");
            }

        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn2.Text = Jugadas();
            btn2.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn3.Text = Jugadas();
            btn3.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn4.Text = Jugadas();
            btn4.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn5.Text = Jugadas();
            btn5.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void lblturno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn6.Text = Jugadas();
            btn6.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn7.Text = Jugadas();
            btn7.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn8.Text = Jugadas();
            btn8.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn9.Text = Jugadas();
            btn9.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Probe el codigo y es funcional.
Te dejo el codigo, falta validar la parte diagonal. Verifica los nombres de cada uno de tus botones y sus eventos.
Te recomiendo que pongas una imagen de una equis y un circulo, se veria genial.
Pd: Se puede optimizar más y hacer más bonito en cuanto a diseño.
Saludos!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int turno = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            habilitar();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            deshabilitar();
        }

        void deshabilitar()
        {
            btn1.Enabled = false;
            btn2.Enabled = false;
            btn3.Enabled = false;
            btn4.Enabled = false;
            btn5.Enabled = false;
            btn6.Enabled = false;
            btn7.Enabled = false;
            btn8.Enabled = false;
            btn9.Enabled = false;

        }
        void habilitar()
        {
            btn1.Enabled = true;
            btn2.Enabled = true;
            btn3.Enabled = true;
            btn4.Enabled = true;
            btn5.Enabled = true;
            btn6.Enabled = true;
            btn7.Enabled = true;
            btn8.Enabled = true;
            btn9.Enabled = true;
        }
        public string Jugadas()
        {
            string variacion = "";
            if (turno == 1)
            {
                variacion = "x";
                turno = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                variacion = "o";
                turno = 1;
            }
            lbljugadas.Text = turno.ToString();
            return variacion;
        }

        void validar()
        {
            //Validacion horizontal
            if (btn1.Text == "x" && btn2.Text == "x" && btn3.Text == "x")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 1");
            }
            else if (btn4.Text == "x" && btn5.Text == "x" && btn6.Text == "x")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 1");
            }
            else if (btn7.Text == "x" && btn8.Text == "x" && btn9.Text == "x")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 1");
            }

            if (btn1.Text == "o" && btn2.Text == "o" && btn3.Text == "o")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 2");
            }
            else if (btn4.Text == "o" && btn5.Text == "o" && btn6.Text == "o")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 2");
            }
            else if (btn7.Text == "o" && btn8.Text == "o" && btn9.Text == "o")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 2");
            }
            //Validadcion vertical
            if (btn1.Text == "x" && btn4.Text == "x" && btn7.Text == "x")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 1");
            }
            else if (btn2.Text == "x" && btn5.Text == "x" && btn8.Text == "x")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 1");
            }
            else if (btn3.Text == "x" && btn6.Text == "x" && btn9.Text == "x")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 1");
            }

            if (btn1.Text == "o" && btn4.Text == "o" && btn7.Text == "o")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 2");
            }
            else if (btn2.Text == "o" && btn5.Text == "o" && btn8.Text == "o")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 2");
            }
            else if (btn3.Text == "x" && btn6.Text == "o" && btn9.Text == "o")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("El jugador ganador es el 2");
            }
            //Validacion diagonal 
        }

        private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            habilitar();
            lbljugadas.Text = turno.ToString();
            validar();
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn1.Text = Jugadas();
            btn1.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn2.Text = Jugadas();
            btn2.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }

        private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn3.Text = Jugadas();
            btn3.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }

        private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn4.Text = Jugadas();
            btn4.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }

        private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn5.Text = Jugadas();
            btn5.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }

        private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn6.Text = Jugadas();
            btn6.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }

        private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn7.Text = Jugadas();
            btn7.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }

        private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn8.Text = Jugadas();
            btn8.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }

        private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn9.Text = Jugadas();
            btn9.Enabled = false;
            validar();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya tambien habia encontrado una solución, igualmente gracias por responder :D (Y)

Comment: @DanielClick si esta respuesta es correcta, considera marcarla como aceptada en incluso votarla positivamente. Así incentivarás a otros usuarios a ayudarte en otra ocasión. Un saludo